# Sort items depending on how much times they are referenced in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a collection of items, each item has a type (Fruit, Vegetable etc.) and an ID:

```
type: 'Fruit',
_id: '0'

type: 'Vegetable',
_id: '1'

type: 'Fruit',
_id: '2'
```

Then I have a collection of buys, each buy references an item:

```
item_id: '2'

item_id: '1'

item_id: '0'

item_id: '2'
```

For now I can get the top bought items with the following code:

```
buySchema.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$item_id", numFills: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { numFills: -1 } }
]).limit(10).exec(function (err, top) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send('error');
    return res.status(200).send(top);
});
```

This code outputs the following json:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "numFills": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "0",
    "numFills": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "numFills": 1
  }
]
```

What I want now is a top list for each type (One for Fruits, another for Vegetables etc), something like this:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Fruits",
        "items": [
            {
                "_id": "2",
                "numFills": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": "0",
                "numFills": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Vegetables",
        items: [
            {
                "_id": "1",
                "numFills": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you,

- `$lookup` to join two collections. I have used [uncorelated lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-aggregation)
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array. Because we can't sort the array
- `$sort` to sort in descending order
- `$group` to reconstruct the array by `type`

Script is here

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "buys",
      "let": { iId: "$_id" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: [ "$item_id", "$$iId" ] }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$item_id",
            numFills: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "joinBuys"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$joinBuys" },
  {
    $sort: { "joinBuys.numFills": -1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      items: { $push: "$joinBuys" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AgipU5Un76z)**